# float package: get list of all floats defined with \newfloat?

Tags: floats, environments, package-writing

I develop a new package and as one functionality, I would need to get the list of all floats defined using the `\newfloat` command of the `float` package.

I could of course modify this command in `mypackage.sty`, but that would need `mypackage` loaded after `float` and before the usage of `\newfloat`, which I don't consider good. I found that there is a `float@type` counter that says (in a strange way) how many floats have been defined. However, there is no command `\float@by@type{<number>}`, that would return the name of the corresponding environment.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to get back the float environment name from the number associated to it: the output routine operates just with the numbers. So I guess that the only way is to modify `\newfloat`.

However, the `newfloat` package should have the same functionality as `float` and maintains a `\newfloat@list` macro that contains all the defined float types.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will still leave the question open for a while, maybe someone suggests something useful...

Comment: While the `float` package defines styled floating environments (i.e. with a certain look+feel, with fixed caption position, and only one caption possible) the `newfloat` package does not. So the `newfloat` package does not strictly have the same functionality since they both defines floating environments but with a different aim.